# Typescript import type Eslint: import/named

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I use Eslint for my project, use:

- parser: `@typescript-eslint/parser` 1.4.2
- plugin: `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` 1.4.2
- resolver: `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` 1.1.1
- rule extends: `airbnb-base` and `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`

or you can check my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "import/no-cycle": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", 2],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "off"
  }
}
```

In file `A.ts` I use: `export type Id = string;` and import from `B.ts`: `import { Id } from '../A';`

I tried to use:

```
import A from '../A';
```

and call A.Id but ide throw error:

> A only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here

Two way has an error, one from `eslint`, one from IDE (Vs Code, maybe Tshint)

Can you help me fix one of them?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that your error is related to the Eslint. From what I can see, it seems to be a basic Typescript error.

Your `A.ts` does not contain a default export. In order to import the entire module from `A.ts` you should use

```
import * as A from '../A';
```

See also the [Typsescript documentation on `import` statements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import)

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/named.md) for `import/named`:

> Note that **type imports and exports**, as used by Flow, **are always ignored**.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this ?

```
import A as A from '../A';
```